# AOSP 5.1.1 error: could not load boot.img

Tags: android, android-source

This is my code:

```
fastboot flashall -w
error: could not load boot.img
```

I can run it in emulator, but when I flash it to device, it reports an error:

```
could not load boot.img
```

How can I get the boot.img file working?

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this problem by copying the boot.img to ${OUT_DIR_COMMON_BASE}/${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/target/product/generic/ and triggered the command. But I failed because I am flashing the wrong device. You may succeed if you flash the correct device.